# Be Kind, Please Rewind: Do you have to watch the tapes to the end?

Tags: achievements, resident-evil-7

There is a trophy/achievement which requires you to watch all video tapes in a single playthrough:

> Be Kind, Please Rewind
>
> Watch all the videotapes in a single playthrough.

Do you have to watch them all to the end to unlock the trophy/achievement? Or can you start them and then drop out?

Comment: As of right now, the only thing I could find is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yd9HXij1SA) comment on a video guide that was posted on true achievements.  The commenter responded to their own comment saying it does work.  I'm not posting as an answer since its a YouTube comment...

Comment: @TimmyJim: Hmmm, yeah bit difficult to judge the credibility on that one, but thanks for the find none the less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just got this trophy today. You DO NOT need to watch the tapes until the end. You can just play them, and once they start you can pause and stop them.

This is with the exception of the 4th and final tape which cannot be skipped. Although the trophy will pop once you start the tape, assuming you have started the other 3 tapes already.