# Are videos tapes optional?

Tags: resident-evil-7

Collectable VHS tapes can be played using a VCR. The parts are interactive and played in first-person perspective as the character in the video. Are these sections completely optional? Are there rewards?

video pause screen:

[image]

The sections mimic the look of a VHS tape playing on CRT display and can be more difficult than the main game due to lower visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first three video tapes are optional. There are four of them, and the final one is not missable because you walk into a room and are forced to watch it. You don't have to watch any of the first three tapes, but they do give you clues to upcoming areas and provide a bit of background. The third tape in particular provides information you need to avoid a trap.

You'll receive a Trophy/Achievement for playing through all four of them.

Comment: It is interesting you say `"You'll receive a Trophy/Achievement for playing through all four of them"`... are you suggesting you need to fully complete all of them for the trophy? [as per this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299360/be-kind-please-rewind-do-you-have-to-watch-the-tapes-to-the-end)

Comment: @musefan I'm not really sure about this, as achievement popped out for me once I've started to watch 4th video.

Comment: @lentinant: That would suggest you are not required to watch them to the end.

Comment: @musefan that's what I imply. Still, player can always rewatch all tapes just before final major location, if my speculation is incorrect.

Comment: @lentinant: Ah yeah, that's a very good suggestion. I am 2 in on my 2nd play and skipped both, so I will find out for sure soon enough